# Elementary proof that a bijective morphism between smooth algebraic varieties is an isomorphism?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

Let $f:W\rightarrow V$ be a bijective morphism of smooth (irreducible) algebraic varieties over the complex numbers. It is a fact that $f$ is an isomorphism. This fact is typically seen as a special case of the corresponding fact when $V$ is normal and $k(W)$ is separably generated over $k(V)$. Relatively heavy machinery and definitions go into proving the latter fact. I was wondering if there was a more elementary proof in the smooth case, perhaps from an analytic perspective, viewing smooth algebraic varieties as complex manifolds and a morphism as locally being the restriction of polynomials on affine charts.

Comment: You really ought to say characteristic zero somewhere - there are plenty of counterexamples in positive characteristic.

Comment: Thank you. I'm mainly interested in the case where the field is the complex numbers. I've edited my question now.